# Threading excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Can I have multiple threads in Excel. I need a counter to show the time elapsed. The thread would have a loop which would update the counter and then sleep for a second. This would (hopefully) take care of excel freezing up while calculating. Along that line, is it possible to have excel update while it calculates. By updating, I mean that the screen would continue to update, rather than freezing. However, I have not tested 2010 and so have no idea whether this is still a problem (it is in 2007).

Comment: Not enough info. What kind of counter? Where should it display? What happens in the background that would justify multi-threading?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739089/vba-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.